# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to release an ABRecordRef

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-foundation

I've got the following class that is a wrapper around an ABPerson (ABRecordRef):

```
@interface Recipient : NSObject {
 ABRecordRef person;
}

- (id)initWithPerson:(ABRecordRef)person;

@end

@implementation 

- (id)initWithPerson:(ABRecordRef)_person {
 if(self = [super init]) person = CFRetain(_person);
 return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
 if(person) CFRelease(person);

 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I've left some of the methods out, but they aren't relevant to this question.

Everything works fine, except I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the `if(person) CFRelease(person);` line.  Why does this happen?  I'm not calling CFRelease or CFRetain at all anywhere else in my app.

Edit, another note:  If I add this right before the CFRelease line:

```
NSLog(@"retain count is %d", CFGetRetainCount(person));
```

It prints `retain count is 1`

Comment: Is it possible that the ABRecordRef `person` object has some internal object that gets de-ref'd before CFRelease has been called??

Comment: It's possible, but I've looked, and I can't think of where it would be.

Comment: well there is nothing wrong with that code that I can see, so either you are doing something in other methods or Justin has the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel sheepish.  I had the following code:

```
// getting the address
CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, addressIndex);

NSString *_street = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict,
    kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
if(_street != nil) street = _street;
```

Apparently, CFDictionaryGetValue doesn't make a copy... and that's probably why it doesn't have `Copy` in the function name.  I wasn't retaining it, and so CFRelease(person) was causing street to be released after it was already reclaimed.

I guess the rest of the code in the class was relevant.  Sorry, I'll try to not make this mistake when posting here in the future.